# A regular expression for an automaton which accepts strings with no more than 3 consecutive zeros

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

This is the automaton I want to find the regular expression for:
[image: an automaton with 5 states]

As you see, states Q1 to Q4 are accepted and Q5 is a kind of trap. This automaton accepts strings that have no more than 3 consecutive zeros.
Can anybody help finding a regular expression for this?

Note : What I tried ...
I defined A:=(0+00+000)
So the automata accepts the strings which contain no consecutive A's. But I don't know how to find that kind of regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: A string with no more than 3 consecutive zeroes has the general form
$$0^{p_1} 1 0^{p_2} 1 0^{p_3} 1 \ldots,$$
where $p_i \leq 3$. Try expressing that structure as a regular expression.